Not able to see my web application on browser which is deployed in microk8s kubernetes
This is my nodeport yaml file

I am not able to see my application on browser. The application is deployed in microk8s on ec2 ubuntu instance. I am able to see my content via curl http://ip:nodeport on the instance but not on browser. The nodeport is opened on Security group as well. The content of my application are showing inside the pod. i have done My Rnd but still not able to figure out the reason.
I have also used loadbalancer service type. It still gives the same issue, by curl it is giving but not on browser

You don't seem to have actually included the YAML file in the question; can you [edit] it?  (Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.)  Does your application code work in other contexts; does your setup work in local Kubernetes environments like Minikube?

I dont have any local setup. please suggest me something to debug th issue

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
